# How to automate shadow dom elements on browser by integrating shady dom api?

Tags: selenium, polymer, shadow-dom, shady-dom

We are facing issues while automating the shadow dom elements using selenium web driver on safari browser.

The main issue we are facing is that we are not able to send keys to the text boxes which are in shadow-root. We tried to set value of textbook using javascript but that too is not working.

Above functionality is working fine with Firefox, but problem is with Safari.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I removed your screenshot of code. You must show relevant code and html **as plain text**. Try to build an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that will fit the format of a good question here.
 Then take a little tour here to see what question get answers nowadays. Re-read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38562300/how-can-do-automation-testing-regression-functional-like-we-do-with-selenium-o